# Receber 12 elementos e separá-los em 3 listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell-script

Preciso receber três listas gerados no shell para processar no Python:

```
l1=4 3 2 1
l2=2 1 3 4
l3=1 2 3 4
```

No shell script passo desta forma:

```
python3 orth_median.py ${o_l1[*]} ${o_l2[*]} ${o_l3[*]}
```

O Python recebe 12 números.

No python eu fui obrigada converter os 12 números em 3 listas para ter novamente as 3 listas. Esta é a melhor forma ou existe outra forma de fazer? Sou iniciante trabalhando com shell script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)>11:
        size1=len(sys.argv[1:])/3 
        l1=[sys.argv[1:][0],sys.argv[1:][1],sys.argv[1:][2],sys.argv[1:][3]]
        l2=[sys.argv[1:][4],sys.argv[1:][5],sys.argv[1:][6],sys.argv[1:][7]]
        l3=[sys.argv[1:][8],sys.argv[1:][9],sys.argv[1:][10],sys.argv[1:][11]]
        A=np.array(generate_matrix(l1, int(size1)))
        B=np.array(generate_matrix(l2, int(size1)))
        C=np.array(generate_matrix(l3, int(size1)))
        M = orth_median1(A, B, C)
        print('o_m', M)
    else:
        print('No arguments provided.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a [sintaxe de *slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para pegar um trecho específico do `sys.argv` - lembrando que [o primeiro elemento de `sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) (na posição zero) é o nome do script, então os números estarão nas posições 1 a 12 (ou seja, você deveria verificar se ele tem pelo menos 13 elementos):

```py
if len(sys.argv) >= 13:
    l1 = sys.argv[1:5]
    l2 = sys.argv[5:9]
    l3 = sys.argv[9:13]
```

Assim, `l1` terá os elementos dos índices 1 a 4 (o valor final não é incluso), `l2` terá dos índices 5 a 8 e `l3` terá dos índices 9 a 12.

---

Outra opção para fazer a mesma coisa:

```py
l1, l2, l3 = [ sys.argv[n:n + 4] for n in range(1, 13, 4) ]
```

Eu uso um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) de 1 a 12, pulando de 4 em 4 (ou seja, os números 1, 5 e 9), e para cada um desses números, pego um *slice* do número até 4 posições depois. Também uso uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), que cria uma lista com as 3 sublistas, e faço a atribuição múltipla, que atribui estas sublistas diretamente para `l1`, `l2` e `l3`.

Com isso as listas serão respectivamente `['4', '3', '2', '1']`, `['2', '1', '3', '4']` e `['1', '2', '3', '4']`.

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas para calcular o `size1`, você pode usar o operador de divisão inteira `//`, que já retorna um valor inteiro (assim não precisará chamar `int` depois). E como você está usando `sys.argv[1:]` (ou seja, ignorando o primeiro elemento de `sys.argv`), é mais simples subtrair 1 do tamanho, em vez de criar outra sub-lista só para isso.

E também é possível já criar os arrays `A`, `B` e `C` de uma vez (se não for usar as listas `l1`, `l2` e `l3` para mais nada):

```py
size1 = (len(sys.argv) - 1) // 3

# criar os arrays de uma vez
A, B, C = [ np.array(generate_matrix(sys.argv[n:n + 4], size1)) for n in range(1, 13, 4) ]
```

Comment: Sua resposta me mostra que preciso aprender mais. Obrigada! Na ultima linha de código  que vc postou vc feiz duas tarefas numa soa linha. como poderia colocar em duas linhas de código?

Comment: @shermila Seria isso: https://repl.it/repls/TiredColossalQuarks#main.py ? Outra coisa: Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.